'Wrapping' an object in geometry nodes (raycasting), combine multiple raycast?

I'm trying to 'wrap' an object using geometry nodes (raycasting).
The thing I want (in short);

Plane starts above monkey (monkey is not visible in final render)
Plane animates down and reveals the shape of the monkey (like it is
wrapping around the mesh)
This continues till the bottom of the monkey.

The problem;

The plane is casting rays upwards(?) now,so it only works untill the more narrow part of the monkey is reached (since the rays connect to the more outward parts of the monkey)


The question;
I don't know how i can realize what i want, maybe multiple raycast nodes (but how?)
Any suggestions, tips or help are really welcome.
Blend file;


You can upload your blend file using https://blend-exchange.com
